# Does Sitecore support Azure AD B2C?

Tags: sitecore-client, azure, azure-ad

I was checking online about integration possibilities for Identity Management solutions like Azure AD with Sitecore.

I could find some good articles like,

- [Integration with Sitecore on Azure PaaS](https://exploringsitecore.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-on-azure-paas/)
- [Architecture choices with Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/architecture-choices-for-integrating-azure-ad-with-sitecore)

But nothing on supporting social authentication.

Does Sitecore apps support authentication using Azure AD B2C for Social Identity Providers?

Comment: I didn't find anything about Sitecore being compatible with Azure AD B2C, however, I was able to find some good stuff like these:
-  https://devandme.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/authenticating-a-sitecore-external-user-as-a-customer-via-azure-b2c-part-1/
- https://xcentium.com/blog/2017/10/03/authenticating-a-sitecore-external-user-via-azure-ad-b2c-gotcha-list

Answer (score 1):

It could certainly be done, but it'll require some hand tooling.

Aside from the articles linked by @Vinicius you should take a look at [Create an ASP.NET web app with Azure Active Directory B2C sign-up, sign-in, profile edit, and password reset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi).  This talks about using B2C in a regular .NET web app - which is essentially what we're talking about, since Sitecore relies on the standard .NET authentication and authorization subsystems.

One thing to note is that the documentation talks a lot about setting up on OWIN, and you may need some additional support to get that going.  Take a look at [this Federated Authentication article by MVP Bas Lijten](http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/), and [the Sitecore.Owin GitHub Project by Vyacheslav Pritykin](https://github.com/VyacheslavPritykin/Sitecore-Owin).

Comment: Might be worth/better to upgrade to Sitecore 9 and use the built-in Federated Authentication using OWIN middlewares now.